# C# ASP.NET json objects to array

Tags: asp.net, json.net

I am stuck on this error. This is my JSON data:

```
{
 "date": "2016-08-26",
 "time_of_day": "14:19",
 "request_time": "2016-08-26T14:19:59+01:00",
 "station_name": "Derby",
 "station_code": "DBY",
 "departures": {
   "all": [
     {
       "mode": "train",
       "service": "22152000",
       "train_uid": "C65080"
     },
     {
       "mode": "train",
       "service": "22150000",
       "train_uid": "C65145"
     },
     {
       "mode": "train",
       "service": "22180008",
       "train_uid": "C70700"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

What I am trying to do is add the service json object to an array, after this I want to increment through the service list and add each service to a separate API call. This is my code:

```
        dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        dynamic departures = content.departures;
        dynamic DepartTimes = departures.all;
        JArray items = ((JArray)DepartTimes["service"]);
        int serviceLength = items.Count;


        for (int i = 0; i < serviceLength; i++)
        {
            //next api call containing array increment
        }
```

The error seems to be here :

```
JArray items = ((JArray)DepartTimes["service"]);
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You have  json data in an array or you want to add it to some array

Comment: I want to add the service objects to an array.

Comment: `DepartTimes` doesn't have a property `service`.

Comment: What do you expect that line to do? DepartTimes looks like it is an array of objects so trying to use an indexer on it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is -

```
var json = "json";
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

JArray arr = new JArray();
foreach(JObject o in d.departures.all){
    arr.Add(o["service"]);
}

Console.Write(arr.Count); //output : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided Json data is not proper. Second and third items must have open curly braces (**{**)

In addition, an example working code may be:

```
dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json));
JArray items = (JArray)content.departures.all;     

var newArray = items.Select(x=>x["service"].ToString()).ToArray();
```